# How can I overlay a rounded shadow to a text, inside a button?

Tags: html, css, angular, overlay

I would like to add a round-light glowing effect on a wide rectangular button, containing a certain text, on mouse over. I am trying to figure out how to use the box-shadow for this, but I think I should be able to achieve what I want by adding a "ghost" div inside the button, above the text (here it comes the overlay?) and I would then apply the box-shadow to this ghost div and not to the button itself (because I don't want the whole button borders getting shadowed, only a tiny dot in the middle of it). Applying a border-radius: 100% to the ghost div, will then provide a perfect rounded shadow. How can I manage these two elements (the text area and the ghost div) in overlay, inside my button? Thanks a lot!!

Here is my starting code:

HTML:

```
<button type="button" mat-flat-button>
  <div class="glow-fx"></div> <!-- The "ghost" div, responsible of the round glowing effect-->
  {{button.label}} <!-- The button text -->
</button>
```

CSS:

```
button {
    display:flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 162px;
    height: 26px;
    color: black;
    background-color: #aa8b0f;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

button:hover {
    transition: 0.5s;
    background-color: #edc00a;
}

.glow-fx {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Comment: It would help if you could mock up an image of what it should look like.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp

Comment: Would a pseudo element be useful here rather than adding a whole div to the HTML?

Comment: What effect you need is not clear. Please share your look a like image effect?

Comment: I think this is what you want for your button https://codepen.io/akash-yadav12/pen/BaLbgaB  refer this pen for the box-shadow code, just reverse the hover effect

Comment: Also I have created this visual editor for box-shadow https://visual-editor-box-shadow.netlify.app/

Answer (score 0):

using text-shadow on your button css file. choose the size and color what ever you want.

```html
button:hover {
    transition: 0.5s;
    background-color: #edc00a;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px #0000ff;
}
```